# JSON RPC Load Testing / Stress Testing Tool

Tags: json-rpc, quorum

I am trying to test my quorum setup by load testing it.

Are there any JSON RPC Load Testing / Stress Testing Tools? Does Postman or SOAP UI supports JSON/RPC calls?

Comment: JSON RPC and you ask if postman supports this? Of course, it can sends JSON data ;)  SOAP UI is XMl, so of course it does not work with JSON rpc

Comment: thanks bro/. but does postman supports RPC calls?  never heard of anyone using postman to load test geth rpc

Comment: Something like this should help [Trebuchet Framework](https://medium.com/@yeh.jxraymond/load-test-private-ethereum-network-with-trebuchet-framework-f65541c5c28b), it is new and under development.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few out there today:

- [Chainbench](https://github.com/chainstacklabs/chainbench) by Chainstack
- [Flood](https://github.com/paradigmxyz/flood) by Paradigm